# php strip html tags and it's data and insert into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a `php` project that connects to imap and insert emails into `MySQL`. I added UI to reply to the email by which it canned them together. I am having one issue. If I send an email to someone it send all data fine, if the person reply it reinserts everything again. I would like to just insert the person reply and strip out the rest of the message. how can I do this? Any suggestions?

I tried wrapping the entire insert with `< section >` tag and tried to use `preg_replace` to 
ignore all it's content but no luck.

This is what my insert looks like

```
$message=strip_tags($message, "<br><p><u><span><hr>");
$message=preg_replace("/(<br\ ?\/?>)+/", "<br/>", $message);
$message= preg_replace('/<section[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/section[^>]*>/', '', $message);

$message=clean("<br/><hr><u>Received On $rep_date / $from_email</u><br/>$message");

mysql_query("UPDATE USER SET INFO = CONCAT('$message',INFO) WHERE ID='$id'");
```

The Data stored in MySQL looks like this

```
<section> <p>Test data</p> etc </section>
```

This works but just it reinserts everything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$start = strpos($message,'<section>')+9;
$end = strpos($message,'<section/>');
$content = strip_tags(substr($message,$start,$end),"<br><p><u><span><hr>");
```

PS: Don't forget to sanitize!

Comment: Thanks Etherous for your suggestion. i tried this but it stripped from the email.

Comment: stripped everything from the email.

Comment: Oh, right. Include the permitted tags like you had in the question

Comment: yea i have that too but same. i analyze the email in outlook and i found that Microsoft stripped the open <section> tag but the closing one is there </section> :( .. in MySQL both of there are there. any other suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, when it's PHP, I have to get my hands on it to troubleshoot it. With this type of question, there's so many factors. If it were me, I would just use a form, and give them a textarea to enter their content

Comment: can i strip start something like this? <a name="_MailOriginal">. this is where the original message starts.

Comment: Of course. Just replace the start and end indices with where you want to cut out the content you're interested in